# I can't figure out how to set multi-line xticklabels when reading labels from a list - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

As the title suggests, I am having trouble finding any documentation on how to print multi-line xticklabels onto my graph when reading from two separate lists. I have heard theories on how to make a separate invisible x-axis and then set the second row of labels off of that, but I have yet to see any code that would explain how that would be done. Thoughts? Thanks for your time.

```
from inventoryClass import stockItem

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotInventory(itemRecords) :

    stockBegin = []
    stockFinish = []  
    stockID = []   
    stockItems = []
    for rec in itemRecords.values() :
        stockBegin.append(rec.getStockStart())
        stockFinish.append(rec.getStockOnHand())
        stockID.append(rec.getID())
        stockItems.append(rec.getName())
    N = len(stockBegin)    
    tuple(stockBegin)
    tuple(stockFinish)

    ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, stockBegin, width, color='r')
    rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, stockFinish, width, color='c')
    ymax = ax.get_ylim()    
    ax.set_ylim(0, (max(ymax) + 30))    



    # add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
    ax.set_ylabel('Inventory')
    ax.set_title('Stock start and end inventory, by item')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(stockItems)
    ax.set_xticklabels(stockID)    
    ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Start', 'End'))

    def autolabel(rects) :

        for rect in rects :
            height = rect.get_height()
            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                    '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

    autolabel(rects1)
    autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

Example of what I am trying to accomplish here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join your two lists with a new line character. You can pass the list into [`ax.set`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set.html?highlight=axes%20set#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xlab1 = [ "a", "b", "c"]
xlab2 = ["1", "2", "3"] 
xlabels = [f"{x1}\n{x2}" for x1, x2, in zip(xlab1,xlab2)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_ = ax.bar([0, 3, 6], range(3), width=1)
_ = ax.bar([1, 4, 7], range(3), width=1)
_ = ax.set(xticks=[.5, 3.5, 6.5], xticklabels=xlabels)
```

[image]